Not seeing results in ksqldb query
in ksqldb-cli (Version: 7.1.7)
I defined a stream based on the docs:
https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.11/ksql/docs/developer-guide/create-a-stream.html
The topic contains JSON data but I use String Serdes in the streaming app to read it. I assumed maybe deserialization was the problem but I don't see this error as specified in the docs:

[2018-09-17 12:29:09,929] WARN task [0_10] Skipping record due to
deserialization error. topic=[_confluent-metrics] partition=[10]
offset=[70]
(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer:86)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
KsqlJsonDeserializer failed to deserialize data for topic:
_confluent-metrics  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
((CTRL-CHAR, code 127)): expected a valid value (number, String,
array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Here is the stream def:
    ksql> CREATE STREAM my_stream_2 (uid STRING KEY, message String) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my_topic', VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON') EMIT CHANGES;

Here is the query that's returning nothing.
ksql> select * from my_stream emit changes;
<nothing>
Press CTRL-C to interrupt

I went through the trouble shooting guide https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/ksqldb/troubleshoot-ksql.html and

my topic is populated with new messages as confirmed with a separate consumer
there are no deserialization errors (no errors printed)
there is no predicate


The topic in the error says _confluent-metrics, but that's not your stream topic. To select existing data, did you set auto.offset.reset value to earliest?

@OneCricketeer: that was just sample text from the docs because I got no serialization errors.
